# How can I instruct binary to use different loader then dlyd

Tags: macos

Is it possible to instruct a program in macOS (application/ binary/ script) on which loader to use for load?

Assuming I want my application to not use `dlyd` how can I instruct the program to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There is load command that can be changed to do this, it invalid the sig.
still looking for a better way